# OBS Studio - 'Blurred background copy' effect. Is this possible using only filters?

Tags: obs

I don't know exactly what is the correct/technical name for this effect, but, to illustrate, i'm searching for a way to reproduce this effect in OBS for a live video source (both window, webcam and so on).
[image: Phoenix Launcher]

This effect is also applied in some portrait videos and photos like this:
[image: Another Example]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe OBS can live blurring effect. The effect you want is actually called compositing where there are two layers and one does not have a blur effect and the other one does.

Donkey Kong background is actually scaled and blurred.

This can be done in editing but not live.

Check out Blackmagic Design website and look for free editing/color correction software. It is called [Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/uk/products/davinciresolve).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something which is kind of the same by duplicating the media and changing the transform slightly in multiple times. They have to have color correction and you can tweak the opacity so it looks right. Hope this helps.

Comment: For the 'tweak' part, this should help: http://asawicki.info/news_1391_how_to_equally_blend_multiple_images_in_gimp.html